# How to use Garmin maps in Android app?

Tags: android, maps, garmin

It's my first time asking here, please forgive me about my bad english

Now, I'm developing a GPS app for Android and I use Garmin Maps that I build from OSM data.

My problem is that I don't know if there is some library that can reder the Garmin map or something that can help me

Thank you very much